# JQuery code only playing sound for first div clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio, click

I have been working on a little project for myself after just learning PHP. Basically I have a search bar that prints out words, their meanings, and I am trying to add a button to hear them being spoken. I got some JS code working that played a sound when I clicked on the picture but the issue is that it will only play when I click on the first picture. If I click on one that is below the very top one loaded into the table (how I return my search data) then the sound won't play. How do I get around this?

extras.js

```
var soundPath = "";
var picturePath = "";

var audio;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#soundPic').click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
    var soundPath = $(this).attr('title');

    console.log(soundPath);

    var audio = new Audio(soundPath)
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

The filepath is set in the PHP code to the pictures title, I then retrieve that with the JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your using an ID soundPic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#soundPic').click(function() {
```

So it will only work on one div with ID soundPic. You can only have one ID with soundPic per page. Give all the images a class of sound_pic or whatever you want, if you don't already have classes for them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sound_pic').click(function() {   // and then you just change it to a class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#soundPic').click(function()....
```

This is using an id selector (id="soundPic"). IDs must be unique, you can only have one per page.

change to

```
$('.soundPic').click(function()
```

in your js, and class="soundPic" in your html;

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the audio like this:

```
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
```

Comment: This is not the issue because when I click the first picture more than once the sound will still play.